# Flutter/android How to calculate acceleration relative to ground?

Tags: flutter, accelerometer, android-sensors, magnetometer

Since acceleration is calculated relative to the phone, how can I convert this relative to the earth?

I believe I need to know what angle the phone is at (pitch) and then use trig to normalise the acceleration directions.

Gyroscopic data isn't helpful since it actually provides a rate of change, rather than the actual pitch.

I have tried using the aeyrium package as that should provide pitch and roll, but I believe the calculations to be wrong - having the phone vertically up or vertically down gives the same pitch but a different roll value, which is totally wrong.

Should I be using the magnetometer to get the pitch - would it even do that?

Comment: You need to register for magnetic field sensor also. Then convert the acceleration to world coordinates.

Comment: How would magnetic field help here? I'm currently trying to do it by grabbing the accelerometer with gravity sensor before they start moving, figuring out the direction of gravity and thus how much the phone is rotated, and then using this to transform any subsequent useracceleration events

Comment: To get acceleration relative to the earth, you need to multiply the obtained acceleration by the rotation matrix. The rotation matrix is just the change of bases matrix that convert phone coordinates to world coordinates.